# Unable to connect to sql server using java 8

Tags: java, database, jtds

I'm trying to connect to my sql server 21014 using java 8. But i'm getting error.

```
import java.sql.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class DBConnec
{
    public static void main(String a[])
    {

        try
        {
            String url = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver//localhost:1433/dictionary";   
            Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
            System.out.println("connection created");
            Statement st=conn.createStatement();    
            String sql="select * from data where word LIKE 'hi'";
            ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery(sql);

            if (rs.next()) 
            {
                System.out.println(rs.getString(0));
            }

            if(st!=null)
                st.close();
            if(conn!=null)
                conn.close();
        }
        catch(SQLException sqle)
        {
            sqle.printStackTrace();
        }

        catch(ClassNotFoundException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Exception i'm getting is:

> java.sql.SQLException: The syntax of the connection URL 'jdbc:jtds:sqlserver//localhost:1433/dictionary' is invalid.
>           at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver.setupConnectProperties(Driver.java:241)
>           at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver.connect(Driver.java:181)
>           at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
>           at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
>           at DBConnec.main(DBConnec.java:15)

I'm running my code using this command:

> java -cp .;"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_66\jre\lib\ext\jtds-1.3.0.jar" DBConnec

I've also tried url without writing "sqlserver". But it gives same exception.
Please help.. Thank you..

I've corrected my syntax but now i'm getting exception  like this:

> java.sql.SQLException: Network error IOException: Connection refused: connect
>           at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsConnection.(JtdsConnection.java:434)
>           at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver.connect(Driver.java:183)
>           at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
>           at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
>           at DBConnec.main(DBConnec.java:15)
>       Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
>           at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
>           at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
>           at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
>           at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
>           at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
>           at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
>           at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
>           at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)

Comment: There is a `:` missing after sqlserver

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
String url = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://localhost:1433/dictionary";
```

You missed the colon after `sqlserver`.

You should not be adding JDBC driver JARs to the jre/lib/ext directory.  Learn how to use CLASSPATH properly.

Comment: Now i'm getting exception like this:   java.sql.SQLException: Network error IOException: Connection refused: connect
        at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsConnection.<init>(JtdsConnection.java:434)
        at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver.connect(Driver.java:183)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
        at DBConnec.main(DBConnec.java:15)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
        at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)

Comment: Username?  Password?

Comment: I have not set anything. Can't it be run with default ? @duffymo

Comment: What default?  You're running a database on your local machine.  I assume you set it up.  The admin password won't be a good idea.  Better to learn how to set one up for the application.

Answer (score 1):

The url format for [JTDS is](http://jtds.sourceforge.net/faq.html#urlFormat):

```
jdbc:jtds:<server_type>://<server>[:<port>][/<database>][;<property>=<value>[;...]]
```

So your url should be like:

```
String url = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://localhost:1433/dictionary"; 
                                ^^^____missing colon
```

Comment: Now i'm getting exception like this:   java.sql.SQLException: Network error IOException: Connection refused: connect
        at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsConnection.<init>(JtdsConnection.java:434)
        at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver.connect(Driver.java:183)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
        at DBConnec.main(DBConnec.java:15)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
        at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)